# How can I get Selenium Web Driver to see drop downs that are "hidden"?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Okay, so maybe I am just a little too tired, but for some reason I cannot get selenium to see Ids of drop down choices that only show when they are clicked. For example, https://accounts.google.com/SignUp. If you Inspect the Birth month or gender drop downs, you can see what I am talking about...

tl;dr: how do I get selenium to find ids of hidden elements

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried with?

Comment: var SelectGender = new SelectElement(base.getDriver().FindElement(By.Id("Gender")));
            SelectGender.SelectByValue(gender);

Comment: And, what is the value of `gender `?

Comment: Gender is an id in a div that contains the dropdown <div id="Gender" class=" form-error" aria-invalid="true">

Comment: So, as you can see this is not a select tag. This is `div` so my understanding `SelectElement` class will not work in this case

Comment: Okay, but where else would I be able to select which option?

Comment: See my answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. In this case You have to click open the gender dropdown `div` first which populates the list and make the options unhidden. Then find a target option with appropriate selector and with sufficient wait time. Notice I am using `explicit` wait to wait for the element to be visible.

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[title='Gender']")).Click();

IWebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content'][.='Male']")));
myElement.Click();
```

If you are a beginner I will not suggest you to use Google for any kind of testing. Google's code is complicated and misleading. Find another application for learning.